# Statement about $(I-A)^{-1}$ matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and let denote $I$ the $n \times n$ [identitiy matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_matrix).

**Theorem.** If $(I-A)$ is [invertible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix) and $(I-A)^{-1}$ is a [nonnegative matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonnegative_matrix) and there is such a diagonal element in $(I-A)^{-1}$ which is less then $1$, then at least one of the elements in $A$ is negative.

**Question.** How could we prove this statement?

I've tried to use [Perron–Frobenius theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%E2%80%93Frobenius_theorem) for $(I-A)^{-1}$, but after I've taken the eigenequation I don't know how to use the condition for the diagonal element.

I've also tried [binomial inverse theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_inverse_theorem) and [Woodbury matrix identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity) but they also didn't help me. Although I think using these tools lead us far away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let
$$ B = (I-A)^{-1}, \qquad A = I-B^{-1}, $$
and let $B_{mm}<1$, $B\geq 0$, and let $e_m$ be the basis vector with $1$ in $m$-th position.

Then $Be_m = v$ has $v_m<1$ and $v\geq 0$, and $(Av)_m = v_m - 1 < 0$.